# Include whitespaces in "No viable alternative at input"-exception in ANTLR4

Tags: exception, antlr, antlr4

When parsing my document and providing code that has no viable alternative with ANTLR4 I properly receive a SyntaxError in my ErrorHandler with the message: `no viable alternative at input '/mig100100moveto250230linetostroke350150moveto200200{'`

because I stripped the whitespaces from the input with the following Lexer-Rules

```
NEWLINE: ('\r')? '\n' -> skip;
WHITESPACE:   (' '|'\t')+ -> skip;
```

it contains no more whitespaces and new-lines.

Is there any way to get a well-formatted message (maybe from the input-stream) inside the ErrorHandler that can be printed out and still contains the white-spaces? E.g.

```
no viable alternative at input '/mig
100 100 moveto
250 230 lineto
stroke

350 150 moveto
200 200 {'
```

I've tried the following method inside of a class that derives from `BaseErrorListener`

```
public override void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
{
    var interval = new Interval(offendingSymbol.StartIndex, offendingSymbol.StopIndex);
    var inputStream = offendingSymbol.InputStream as AntlrInputStream;
    if (inputStream != null)
    {
        // TODO: If you get the source-code without the spaces, use this original text instead.
        var originalText = inputStream.GetText(interval);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Line {0}:{1} {2}", line, charPositionInLine, msg);
    Console.WriteLine("Line {0}:{1} {2}", line, charPositionInLine, originalText);
}
```

But the resulting `originalText` only contains the offending symbol `{` and not where the parser found no viable alternative.

I would be happy if I could get the index, where the parser found no viable alternative (at the start of `/mig`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of skipping the tokens you can set them to the HIDDEN channel.
This will maintain the whitespace when showing error messages.

```
NEWLINE:    ('\r')? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN);
WHITESPACE: (' '|'\t')+  -> channel(HIDDEN);
```